# How can I redirect AppEngine 500 Errors to another location?

Tags: http, google-app-engine

How can I redirect 500 Errors from google appengine to another location.

The following is an example scenario:

All requests to http://example.appspot.com/testfile.ext in case of a 500 error should redirect to http://www.example.com/testfile.ext

This is basically combining the 500 error with a 302 redirect. Is it possible if not is there a work around?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Returning a non-500 error code in case of error is usually a terrible idea - maybe there's a better way to do what you're asking.

Comment: Actually I am trying to create a fail safe. If a user does a request on to app-engine and for some reason it throws a 500 error the request should automatically redirect to my backup server location. This is only to ensure a failsafe.

Answer (score 0):

It can redirect a failure with simplest way I know

```
   try:
    #stuff    
   except:
     self.redirect('http://www.example.com/testfile.ext')
     return
```

Or this slightly more complicated redirect one can modify from 301 to 302

```
def redirect_from_appspot(wsgi_app):
    def redirect_if_needed(env, start_response):
        if env["HTTP_HOST"].startswith('my_app_name.appspot.com'):
            import webob, urlparse
            request = webob.Request(env)
            scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment = urlparse.urlsplit(request.url)
            url = urlparse.urlunsplit([scheme, 'www.my_domain.com', path, query, fragment])
            start_response('301 Moved Permanently', [('Location', url)])
            return ["301 Moved Peramanently",
                  "Click Here" % url]
        else:
            return wsgi_app(env, start_response)
    return redirect_if_needed
```

Case depends if 500 Error is your app or google server. Easiest would be featuring it in gae console we can request app engine team to enable, or yaml or most formal with regex. The easy way is try, except and redirect.

Comment: The method you told only works in handling errors in a case by case basis. Isn't there a method to handle all 500 errors on my app.